# Installing virtualenvwrapper on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with Python 3.6

Tags: python, terminal, raspberry-pi, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have been trying to download/install virtualenvwrapper on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, but I get an error message when using the command "source ~/.profile" in the terminal. I am trying to install OpenCV with python 3.6, but I need to set up virtualenvwrapper.
The error I get when I run "source ~/.profile" is:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

I am following this online guide: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it, had to rewrite the "~/.profile".

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
```

to

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/pythonx.x
```

(`x.x` is the Python version).